# SQL Fiddle - Oracle Stored Procedure not updating rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sqlfiddle

I am trying to learn Oracle stored procedures and I cannot make them run properly on SQL Fiddle or DBfiddle. I don't have access to an installed Oracle database.
Here is my code from http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e53857/5

```
CREATE TABLE user_1 (password varchar(10))
/
create procedure updateUsers
   ( new_p in varchar2)
as
begin
SAVEPOINT before;
  update user_1 set password = 'in proc';
  dbms_output.put_line(SQL%RowCount);
commit;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM); 
end;
/
```

and the query pane

```
insert into user_1 values ('initial');
select password from user_1;
update user_1 set password = 'from query';
SELECT password from user_1;
exec (updateUsers );
select password from user_1;
```

When I look at the last output below the update in the query pane has worked, the stored procedure hasn't changed anything, the value of `password` is still `from query` and there is no error message.

The line ending in the left pane is `/` and  `;` in the right pane.
I would appreciate any help and pointers.
If another online tool is easier to use for Oracle than SQL fiddle I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution!
schema pane, line ending `/` both panes

```
CREATE TABLE user_1 (password varchar(10))
/
create procedure updateUsers
   ( new_p in varchar2)
as
begin
SAVEPOINT before;
  update user_1 set password = new_p;
  dbms_output.put_line(SQL%RowCount);
commit;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM); 
end;
/
```

query pane

```
insert into user_1 values ('initial')/
select password from user_1/
update user_1 set password = 'from query'/
SELECT password from user_1/
begin
  updateUsers('new_pass') ;
end;
/
select password from user_1/
```

output

> PASSWORD
> initial

> PASSWORD
> from query

> PASSWORD
> new_pass

see also extension
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b942cc/3